# How to compare columns of one line in same file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

This is my input file :

```
A B B A  
A A A   
B A B A  
B B  
A A  
A B
```

If all columns are same, I want to print only the first column.
Otherwise, I want to print `multi`.

Desired output :

```
multi  
A  
multi  
B  
A  
multi
```

Can anyone help me?
(I prefer `awk` or `sed`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With AWK:

```
awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { if ($i != $1) { print "multi"; next } }; print $1 }'
```

This processes each line as follows:

- starting from the second field, compare each field to the first;
- if a difference is found, print "multi" and move to the next line;
- if no difference is found (the loop finishes, or is skipped entirely, *e.g.* for a line containing no or one field only), print the first field (and move to the next line).

Answer (score 2):

`awk`/`perl` are the better tools for this job but you can do it with `sed` too:

```
sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]*)([[:blank:]]+\1)*$/\1/;t;s/.*/multi/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{b=$1; gsub($1,""); if (/^\s*$/) {print b} else {print "multi"}}' file         
multi
A
multi
B
A
multi
```